# Data replication in microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

We are trying to move from a monolithic architecture to a microservice architecture. We thought of what would be the best way to segregate our services and started doing so one by one. Now we have a question as to how we should make dependent calls. Let me explain in detail.

Lets say we have different microservices. One of them has details about a product. Other microservices revolve around the product, so they will be a service for transactions, orders, offers etc. All microservices communicate using gRPC.

All these services will be referencing the items microservice that has details of the items (referencing will be done via IDs). So each of the other services will only be having the ID of the Item.

Now the issue (or maybe not) is that when ever we want to see a list of transactions done by a user, we also need details of the items. Similarly list of orders places, again we need details of the items. (not all the details but some of them).

There are two options that we can think of for dealing with the issue.

- One is to make two subsequent calls, once to the transaction or order microservice and than to the item microservice to get the partial details needed. Here we have our own gateway which is extremely efficient in terms of performance and network.
- The other is to copy the partial data using pub/sub that is required by the transaction and order microservice in the service itself. So basically something like a new table in the order microservice and taking a join in the service to serve data. thus killing the need to make dependent calls.

**So first of all is the segregation of the services proper?**

**second which of the 2 methods are a better design**

Note: we have around 10 services that would be dependent on the items database. 
Also on a page there are usually calls to 5-6 microservices. The good thing is that we have our own gateway which makes all calls in parallel. So there will be max 2 sequential calls if we use the first method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no right answer in architecture but to follow best practices. When you have data residing in multiple services and you have to join them , in my opinion it's not a good practice to aggregate it by calling different microservices since it kills the purpose of loosely coupled services. So in your case it's the second design.

It's not a bad practice to keep duplicated data of other services if you are going to achieve loose coupling. Another modification to your design could be use of CQRS/Event sourcing . You will dump all your events in the event store and create read-only model/projections from that event store. It's very powerful pattern but be mindful this is complex pattern and could be overkill.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, But somehow the case here is different. I don't have to take a join here. Its like calling a MS and getting the result. The result has ids of multiple related entities. For getting the details of the related entities I would have to call the resp MS. vs storing a copy of that data at multiple locations.

Comment: if you are calling multiple services to accommodate single request its join. imagine your one dependent microservice is down. you can't compete the request even when other services are up so it's dependency which has to be avoided.  if your client request is calling multiple services then it's not recommended approach.  you either create projections/readonly models or data stay within microservices. it's really give and take approach but try to make your services independent even if you require some duplication.

Comment: duplication doesn't mean you are required to duplicate all the data. imagine booking service can has order staus ( it's in the booking service itself) but when user click the order details you call other service only then to get details.  imgaine order service is down but your booking service is still able to show the booking staus because order staus is there. so it's give and take approach

Comment: Just a warning about replication. This works well when you have a single source of truth. You probably don't want to allow multiple data sources to be written to or updated. An API should act as the router to the correct source of truth and the replications should extend to other data sources as read only models

Comment: A little caveat to that is when you are following the strangler pattern, you might temporarily adopt parallel updates between monolith and strangled schemas, while you develop new microservices

Comment: But in the second approach, how to handle data mofications? For example, Order service replicates data from the Users service, however, some property in the user entity has changed. How to follow up the change in the Order service?

Answer (score 5):

Go with second option "copy the partial data using pub/sub". This is only way to make your microservice truly autonomous and achieve better performance by reducing network calls.

Answer (score -1):

when ever we want to see a list of transactions done by a user => This is basically auditing and eventually analytix.

If you try to solve the exact problem, you will have difficulty in future when you think about expanding it more have having more analytical type of requirements (for example you decide to do more research on user choices).

As you are moving to micro service pattern - a better approach here will be to have your current services made an entry in audits with all the details and eventing will be the best choice here so your auditing(or future analytics module) can be worked on independent. So if all the service produce the necessary events which are required for the auditing/reporting purpose you can build an auditing/reporting micro service which deals with the rest - Yes, it will duplicate data but its always better to keep the audits away from the actual data.